# css keyframes animation with transform not working on SVG

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, svg

When I try to animate an SVG text with a CSS keyframe animation, it won't animate the transform properties. Animating the fill property works in the same animation. So the animation gets executed.

the transform outside of the animation works, so I have no idea why it doesn't work in the animation.

the code only has to work in Chrome.

my SVG(snippet):

```
<text x="274.546" y="331.6133" id="Voer" class="st14 st15 clickable">Voer</text>
```

my CSS code :

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    fill: #ff4a4a;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -20px);
            transform: translate(0, -20px);
  }
  75% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    fill: #ff4a4a;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -20px);
            transform: translate(0, -20px);
  }
  75% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
.clickable {
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s infinite ;
          animation: pulse 3s infinite ;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -20px);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, -20px);
          transform: translate(0, -20px);
}
```

fiddle with recreated problem: https://jsfiddle.net/17ecnuLu/

```css
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    fill: #ff4a4a;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -20px);
            transform: translate(0, -20px);
  }
  75% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    fill: #ff4a4a;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -20px);
            transform: translate(0, -20px);
  }
  75% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    fill: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
.clickable {
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s infinite ;
          animation: pulse 3s infinite ;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -20px);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, -20px);
          transform: translate(0, -20px);
}

/*SVG MARKUP */

* {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
 .st0{opacity:0.3;fill:#CBDB2A;}
 .st1{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#306F9C;}
 .st2{fill:none;stroke:#306F9C;stroke-width:0.144;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st3{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#1ABECB;stroke:#1ABECB;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st4{fill:none;stroke:#1ABECB;stroke-width:0.144;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st5{fill:#1ABECB;stroke:#1ABECB;stroke-width:0.144;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st6{font-family:'HWTArtz';}
 .st7{font-size:5.52px;}
 .st8{font-size:5.4223px;}
 .st9{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#1ABECB;}
 .st10{fill:none;stroke:#1ABECB;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st11{font-family:'MuseoSansRounded-700';}
 .st12{font-size:20px;}
 .st13{letter-spacing:1;}
 .st14{font-family:'MuseoSansRounded-1000';}
 .st15{font-size:12px;}
 
  .st16{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#E11B22;stroke:#DD1F26;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st17{fill:#E11B22;stroke:#DD1F26;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st18{fill:#D1D3D4;}
 .st19{font-size:10px;}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 831 442.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 831 442.7;" xml:space="preserve">

<g id="Zoniënwoud">
 <polygon class="st0" points="535,442.7 535,440.3 531.6,437.2 531.6,433.4 527.8,425 531.1,419.2 537.4,410.8 537.4,394.5 
  528,360.9 526.3,347.7 539.8,339.8 539.8,329.5 548.7,324.4 544.6,317.5 544.6,304.5 544.6,280.7 552.7,254.8 557.5,251.9 
  557.5,238.5 577,232.5 581.1,256.3 575.5,259.4 577,269 582.5,272.1 593.5,263.7 584.4,235.6 578.4,201.5 567.1,170.8 548.2,180.7 
  540.3,153.1 548.9,144.2 546,125 547.7,116.8 570,102.4 582,132.7 593.8,135.8 606.5,134.3 606.5,131.7 597.6,125.2 591.1,113.9 
  589.2,104.1 602.9,83.7 613.5,72.9 610.3,69.8 603.9,56.1 592.6,40.7 585.9,29.2 577.9,15.3 563.1,6.9 554.4,11.9 545.5,19.4 
  537.6,23.7 522,25.1 514.8,21.1 500.2,19.4 425.1,49.4 418.8,47 412.6,54.7 395.5,61.1 351.4,77.7 361,112.7 362.7,120.4 
  376.1,143.7 394.1,165.8 434.9,165.8 463.7,201.8 463.7,209 449.8,229.1 439.2,229.1 407.8,267.3 404.2,267.3 397.5,259.4 
  394.3,249.1 389.1,238 381.4,230.6 370.6,241.4 360.3,235.4 357.4,238 348,236.3 340.1,244.3 332.2,239.7 318,247.9 310.8,240.7 
  302.7,248.8 312.7,262.5 306.7,278.3 310.1,284.1 309.4,288.7 285.6,294.2 262.8,301.1 257.8,272.1 249.4,272.1 249.4,259.6 
  242.2,259.6 238.1,252.2 235.2,250.5 225.9,255.8 220.3,245.9 214.8,246.7 205.7,237.5 199,235.6 191.5,239.7 185.3,239.7 
  165.4,259.6 160.8,256.7 141.6,278.6 124.6,268.7 102,287.9   "/>
</g>
<g id="Water">
 <path class="st1" d="M614,36.2L614,36.2c0.5-0.2,1-0.3,1.6-0.3h5.3c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4,0l0,0c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.1
  c2.6,0.6,4.3,0.9,5.2,1c1,0.1,2.9-0.2,5.6-1l1.1-0.7l6.5-2.2l17-1.4l24.7-3.1h13l23.2,3.1h11.6l17.6-4l20.4-6l17.6-3.7l23.5-2.6
  l21-3.7l0.2,1.4l-21,3.7l-23.5,2.5l-17.5,3.7L748,29.1l-17.8,4h-11.9L695.1,30h-12.9l-24.6,3.1l-16.9,1.4l-6.2,2.1l-1.4,0.8
  c-0.6,0.3-1.2,0.8-1.8,1.5c-0.7,0.7-1.5,1.9-2.5,3.6c-1,1.7-2.1,3.2-3.3,4.4l-1.8,1.1l-14.9,9.6l-2.3,0.6l-1.1-1.1v-1.4l4.4-5.2
  c0.7-0.9,1-1.7,0.9-2.6c-0.4-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.9-0.6h-6.2l-1.3-8.1l6.4-0.6L614,36.2"/>
 <path class="st2" d="M614,36.2L614,36.2c0.5-0.2,1-0.3,1.6-0.3h5.3c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4,0l0,0c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.1
  c2.6,0.6,4.3,0.9,5.2,1c1,0.1,2.9-0.2,5.6-1l1.1-0.7l6.5-2.2l17-1.4l24.7-3.1h13l23.2,3.1h11.6l17.6-4l20.4-6l17.6-3.7l23.5-2.6
  l21-3.7l0.2,1.4l-21,3.7l-23.5,2.5l-17.5,3.7L748,29.1l-17.8,4h-11.9L695.1,30h-12.9l-24.6,3.1l-16.9,1.4l-6.2,2.1l-1.4,0.8
  c-0.6,0.3-1.2,0.8-1.8,1.5c-0.7,0.7-1.5,1.9-2.5,3.6c-1,1.7-2.1,3.2-3.3,4.4l-1.8,1.1l-14.9,9.6l-2.3,0.6l-1.1-1.1v-1.4l4.4-5.2
  c0.7-0.9,1-1.7,0.9-2.6c-0.4-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.9-0.6h-6.2l-1.3-8.1l6.4-0.6L614,36.2"/>
 <path class="st1" d="M597.2,64.3c0-0.4,0.5-1.3,1.6-2.5c1.1-1.2,1.9-2.1,2.6-2.8c0.6-0.6,1.2-1.1,1.6-1.3c0.5-0.3,0.8-0.3,1.1,0
  c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.4,1.2c0,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.5,1.6c-0.3,0.6-1,1.2-2,2c-1,0.8-1.8,1.4-2.3,2c-0.6,0.6-1.1,0.8-1.6,0.6
  C597.5,65,597.3,64.7,597.2,64.3"/>
 <path class="st2" d="M597.2,64.3c0-0.4,0.5-1.3,1.6-2.5c1.1-1.2,1.9-2.1,2.6-2.8c0.6-0.6,1.2-1.1,1.6-1.3c0.5-0.3,0.8-0.3,1.1,0
  c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.4,1.2c0,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.5,1.6c-0.3,0.6-1,1.2-2,2c-1,0.8-1.8,1.4-2.3,2c-0.6,0.6-1.1,0.8-1.6,0.6
  C597.5,65,597.3,64.7,597.2,64.3"/>
 <polyline class="st1" points="554.2,100.5 559.2,97.6 565.7,91.1 570,83.7 577,75.3 583.7,70 585.6,69.8 587.5,71.9 589.9,74.1 
  590.4,75.3 589.2,76 584.9,78.7 582,82.3 579.6,88.3 577.9,90.2 574.8,91.9 572.4,94.5 568.8,97.9 560.7,104.8 556.8,105.8 
  555.1,104.8 553.5,101.9 553.2,101 554.2,100.5  "/>
 <polygon class="st2" points="554.2,100.5 559.2,97.6 565.7,91.1 570,83.7 577,75.3 583.7,70 585.6,69.8 587.5,71.9 589.9,74.1 
  590.4,75.3 589.2,76 584.9,78.7 582,82.3 579.6,88.3 577.9,90.2 574.8,91.9 572.4,94.5 568.8,97.9 560.7,104.8 556.8,105.8 
  555.1,104.8 553.5,101.9 553.2,101  "/>
 <path class="st3" d="M614,36.2L614,36.2c0.5-0.2,1-0.3,1.6-0.3h5.3c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4,0l0,0c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.1
  c2.6,0.6,4.3,0.9,5.2,1c1,0.1,2.9-0.2,5.6-1l1.1-0.7l6.5-2.2l17-1.4l24.7-3.1h13l23.2,3.1h11.6l17.6-4l20.4-6l17.6-3.7l23.5-2.6
  l21-3.7l0.2,1.4l-21,3.7l-23.5,2.5l-17.5,3.7L748,29.1l-17.8,4h-11.9L695.1,30h-12.9l-24.6,3.1l-16.9,1.4l-6.2,2.1l-1.4,0.8
  c-0.6,0.3-1.2,0.8-1.8,1.5c-0.7,0.7-1.5,1.9-2.5,3.6c-1,1.7-2.1,3.2-3.3,4.4l-1.8,1.1l-14.9,9.6l-2.3,0.6l-1.1-1.1v-1.4l4.4-5.2
  c0.7-0.9,1-1.7,0.9-2.6c-0.4-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.9-0.6h-6.2l-1.3-8.1l6.4-0.6L614,36.2"/>
 <path class="st4" d="M614,36.2L614,36.2c0.5-0.2,1-0.3,1.6-0.3h5.3c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4,0l0,0c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.1
  c2.6,0.6,4.3,0.9,5.2,1c1,0.1,2.9-0.2,5.6-1l1.1-0.7l6.5-2.2l17-1.4l24.7-3.1h13l23.2,3.1h11.6l17.6-4l20.4-6l17.6-3.7l23.5-2.6
  l21-3.7l0.2,1.4l-21,3.7l-23.5,2.5l-17.5,3.7L748,29.1l-17.8,4h-11.9L695.1,30h-12.9l-24.6,3.1l-16.9,1.4l-6.2,2.1l-1.4,0.8
  c-0.6,0.3-1.2,0.8-1.8,1.5c-0.7,0.7-1.5,1.9-2.5,3.6c-1,1.7-2.1,3.2-3.3,4.4l-1.8,1.1l-14.9,9.6l-2.3,0.6l-1.1-1.1v-1.4l4.4-5.2
  c0.7-0.9,1-1.7,0.9-2.6c-0.4-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.9-0.6h-6.2l-1.3-8.1l6.4-0.6L614,36.2"/>
 <path class="st1" d="M597.2,64.3c0-0.4,0.5-1.3,1.6-2.5c1.1-1.2,1.9-2.1,2.6-2.8c0.6-0.6,1.2-1.1,1.6-1.3c0.5-0.3,0.8-0.3,1.1,0
  c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.4,1.2c0,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.5,1.6c-0.3,0.6-1,1.2-2,2c-1,0.8-1.8,1.4-2.3,2c-0.6,0.6-1.1,0.8-1.6,0.6
  C597.5,65,597.3,64.7,597.2,64.3"/>
 <path class="st5" d="M597.2,64.3c0-0.4,0.5-1.3,1.6-2.5c1.1-1.2,1.9-2.1,2.6-2.8c0.6-0.6,1.2-1.1,1.6-1.3c0.5-0.3,0.8-0.3,1.1,0
  c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.4,1.2c0,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.5,1.6c-0.3,0.6-1,1.2-2,2c-1,0.8-1.8,1.4-2.3,2c-0.6,0.6-1.1,0.8-1.6,0.6
  C597.5,65,597.3,64.7,597.2,64.3"/>
 <polyline class="st3" points="554.2,100.5 559.2,97.6 565.7,91.1 570,83.7 577,75.3 583.7,70 585.6,69.8 587.5,71.9 589.9,74.1 
  590.4,75.3 589.2,76 584.9,78.7 582,82.3 579.6,88.3 577.9,90.2 574.8,91.9 572.4,94.5 568.8,97.9 560.7,104.8 556.8,105.8 
  555.1,104.8 553.5,101.9 553.2,101 554.2,100.5  "/>
 <polygon class="st4" points="554.2,100.5 559.2,97.6 565.7,91.1 570,83.7 577,75.3 583.7,70 585.6,69.8 587.5,71.9 589.9,74.1 
  590.4,75.3 589.2,76 584.9,78.7 582,82.3 579.6,88.3 577.9,90.2 574.8,91.9 572.4,94.5 568.8,97.9 560.7,104.8 556.8,105.8 
  555.1,104.8 553.5,101.9 553.2,101  "/>
 <text transform="matrix(1.0117 0 0 1 658.5792 51.0534)" class="st6 st7"> </text>
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1.018 669.1387 51.0534)" class="st6 st8"> </text>
 <polyline class="st9" points="566.7,26.8 562.1,27.3 557.8,26.6 554.7,26.8 552.3,28.3 547.7,31.6 542.7,34.7 537.6,36.7 
  531.1,40.3 524.2,43.9 521.1,45.8 495.9,56.8 484.6,60.7 454.1,78.2 447.6,83.7 432.3,95.7 411.1,107.9 400.6,111.5 398.2,112.7 
  397.2,113.5 378,140.3 362.4,167.5 340.3,193.9 328.3,200.8 305.5,223.6 303.6,230.6 309.4,240.7 309.9,242.8 308.4,246.7 
  308.4,247.6 308.9,250 315.6,258.7 316.8,262.7 316.8,266.8 316.1,272.6 315.6,276.4 315.6,281 315.1,286 315.6,288.7 319,297.1 
  319.7,301.6 319,307.4 317.1,313.6 314.7,320.6 313.7,324.2 312,336.4 312,344.1 309.6,357.8 309.6,366.2 306.5,376.3 306,385.6 
  306,399.3 298.3,413.5 297.1,413 304.6,399.1 304.6,385.6 305.1,376 308.2,365.9 308.2,357.8 310.6,344.1 310.6,336.4 312.5,323.9 
  313.5,320.1 315.9,313.1 317.5,306.9 318.3,301.9 317.5,297.5 314.2,288.9 313.7,286.3 314.2,281 314.2,276.4 314.7,272.3 
  315.6,266.6 315.6,263 314.2,259.4 307.5,250.7 307,247.6 307.2,246.2 308.4,242.8 307.9,241.1 301.9,230.8 304.3,222.9 
  327.6,199.6 339.4,192.7 361.2,166.7 376.8,139.4 396.3,112.5 379.2,116.1 370.3,118.5 360.3,119.9 353.1,120.7 331.7,113.9 
  307.5,112.5 275.1,120.7 240,129.1 213.4,129.1 213.6,129.3 212.4,129.1 209.3,129.1 203.3,130 167.1,144.2 123.4,160 90.3,167.5 
  59.5,175.4 41.8,179.2 15.6,183.3 0.5,183.3 0.5,182.1 15.4,182.1 41.5,177.8 59.1,173.9 90,166 122.9,158.8 166.6,143 
  202.8,128.6 209.1,127.6 239.8,127.6 274.8,119.5 307.2,111.1 332.2,112.5 353.1,119.2 360,118.5 370.1,117.1 379,114.7 
  400.3,110.3 410.4,106.5 431.5,94.5 446.7,82.7 453.4,77 483.9,59.2 495.1,55.4 520.3,44.6 523.5,42.7 528.7,39.1 533.3,34.5 
  539.1,32.8 546.3,28.5 549.6,24.4 553.9,21.3 558.7,21.1 565.9,22.7 571.5,26.8 578.9,32.6 580.6,35.7 580.6,42.9 582.7,42.9 
  587.8,42.2 594.5,40 600,39.3 601.2,47.9 594.3,49.9 588,51.5 585.4,51.5 584.2,51.3 580.6,47.5 579.1,45.3 579.1,35.9 577.7,33.5 
  570.5,28 568.3,27.1 566.7,26.8  "/>
 <polygon class="st10" points="566.7,26.8 562.2,27.3 557.8,26.6 554.7,26.8 552.3,28.3 547.8,31.6 542.7,34.7 537.7,36.7 
  531.2,40.3 524.3,43.9 521.2,45.8 496,56.8 484.8,60.7 454.3,78.2 447.9,83.7 432.5,95.7 411.4,107.9 400.9,111.5 398.5,112.7 
  397.5,113.5 378.4,140.3 362.8,167.5 340.7,193.9 328.8,200.8 306,223.6 304.1,230.6 309.8,240.7 310,242.8 308.3,246.7 
  308.3,247.6 309,250 315.9,258.7 317.3,262.7 317.3,266.8 316.6,272.6 316.3,276.4 316.3,281 315.7,286 316.1,288.7 319.4,297.1 
  320.1,301.6 319.4,307.4 317.5,313.6 315.1,320.6 314,324.2 312.3,336.4 312.3,344.1 310.3,357.8 310.3,366.2 306.9,376.3 
  306.3,385.6 306.3,399.3 298.7,413.5 297.7,413 305.3,399.1 305.3,385.6 305.4,376 308.3,365.9 308.3,357.8 311.3,344.1 
  311.3,336.4 313.1,323.9 314,320.1 316.3,313.1 318,306.9 318.7,301.9 318,297.5 314.6,288.9 314,286.3 314.3,281 314.3,276.4 
  315,272.3 316.3,266.6 316.3,263 314.7,259.4 308,250.7 307.5,247.6 307.7,246.2 308.9,242.8 308.4,241.1 302.4,230.8 304.8,222.9 
  328,199.6 339.8,192.7 361.6,166.7 377.2,139.4 396.6,112.5 379.6,116.1 370.7,118.5 360.6,119.9 353.4,120.7 332.1,113.9 
  307.9,112.5 275.6,120.7 240.6,129.1 214,129.1 214.2,129.4 213,129.1 209.9,129.1 203.9,130 167.7,144.2 124.1,160 91,167.5 
  60.4,175.4 42.6,179.1 16.5,183.1 0.5,183.1 0.5,182.1 16.3,182.1 42.4,177.8 59.9,173.9 90.8,166 123.6,158.8 167.2,143 
  203.4,128.8 209.7,128.1 240.3,128.1 275.3,119.7 307.7,111.2 332.6,112.6 353.4,119.2 360.4,118.5 370.5,117.1 379.3,114.7 
  400.6,110.3 410.7,106.5 431.8,94.5 446.9,82.7 453.6,77 484,59.2 495.3,55.4 520.5,44.6 523.6,42.7 528.9,39.1 533.4,34.5 
  539.2,32.8 546.3,28.5 549.7,24.4 554,21.3 558.8,21.1 566,22.7 571.5,26.8 579.2,32.6 581.1,35.7 581.1,43.1 582.8,43.1 
  587.8,42.3 594.5,40.1 600,39.3 601.2,47.9 594.3,49.7 588,51.1 585.4,51.1 584.2,51.1 580.6,47.3 579.1,45.3 579.1,35.9 
  577.7,33.5 570.5,28 568.4,27.1  "/>
</g>
<g id="Gebouwen">
</g>
<g id="Namen">
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 272.5991 151.6133)" class="st11 st12 st13">Fura</text>
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 218.0431 188.6133)" class="st14 st15">Sint-Jan-de-Doper</text>
 <g>
  <g>
   <polygon class="st16" points="305.9,158.2 303,155.3 300.1,158.2 300.5,158.7 300.5,162.6 305.4,162.6 305.4,158.7    "/>
   <polygon class="st16" points="311,161.9 308.1,159 305.1,161.9 305.6,162.3 305.6,166.3 310.5,166.3 310.5,162.3    "/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <polygon class="st16" points="291.6,158.2 288.7,155.3 285.8,158.2 286.3,158.7 286.3,162.6 291.2,162.6 291.2,158.7    "/>
   <polygon class="st16" points="286.1,161.9 283.2,159 280.3,161.9 280.8,162.3 280.8,166.3 285.7,166.3 285.7,162.3    "/>
  </g>
  <polygon class="st16" points="299,165.5 296.1,162.6 293.1,165.5 293.6,166 293.6,169.9 298.5,169.9 298.5,166   "/>
 </g>
 <path class="st16" d="M332,182.7"/>
 <g>
  <polygon class="st16" points="334,184.8 331.1,181.9 328.2,184.8 328.7,185.3 328.7,189.2 333.6,189.2 333.6,185.3   "/>
  <g>
   <line class="st16" x1="331.1" y1="178.1" x2="331.1" y2="183.7"/>
   <line class="st16" x1="329.7" y1="179.4" x2="332.5" y2="179.4"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <circle class="st17" cx="312.5" cy="328.6" r="3.2"/>
</g>
<g id="Referentiepunten">
 <text transform="matrix(0.95 -0.3121 0.3121 0.95 122.4505 152.4042)" class="st18 st11 st19">Maalbeek</text>
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 453.4195 212.28)" class="st18 st11 st12 st13">Zoniënwoud</text>
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 593.3998 16.9999)" class="st18 st11 st12 st13">Vossem</text>
 <g>
  <text x="274.546"  y="331.6133" id="Voer" class="st14 st15 clickable">Voer</text>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you make a demo? (jsfiddle, ...)

Comment: @Paulie_D i'm sorry i was testing around a bit and copied the wrong code, it still doesn't work though(I've edited the code in the question).

Comment: Perhaps you could make a demo?

Comment: @sniels  https://jsfiddle.net/17ecnuLu/ here you go!

Comment: @Paulie_D i've added a jsfiddle! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this if you set the animation for the position on the parent SVG, and the animation for the color on the `text` element.

See https://jsfiddle.net/cgbqq0f6/

**EDIT:**

After some experimentation, it looks like you can't use css transform animations on `path` or `text` elements. You *can*, however, apply these to a wrapper element (such as a generic `g` tag, or a specific one if tied to an ID or class):

```css
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -20px);
            transform: translate(0, -20px);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -20px);
            transform: translate(0, -20px);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorText {
  0% {
    fill: #000000;
  }
  25% {
    fill: #000000;
  }
  50% {
    fill: #ff4a4a;
  }
  75% {
    fill: #000000;
  }
  100% {
    fill: #000000;
  }
}
@keyframes colorText {
  0% {
    fill: #000000;
  }
  25% {
    fill: #000000;
  }
  50% {
    fill: #ff4a4a;
  }
  75% {
    fill: #000000;
  }
  100% {
    fill: #000000;
  }
}

.animatable {
    position: relative;
    fill: #000;
     -webkit-animation: pulse 3s infinite ;
          animation: pulse 3s infinite ;
}

g.animatable {
    position: relative;
    fill: #000;
     -webkit-animation: pulse 2s infinite ;
          animation: pulse 2s infinite ;
}

.animatable text {
    
  -webkit-animation: colorText 3s infinite ;
          animation: colorText 3s infinite ;
}
```

```html
<svg height="60" width="200" id="voer">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red" class="animatable">Voer</text>
    <g class="animatable"><text x="0" y="30" fill="red" class="two">Another</text></g>
    <g class="animatable">
   <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

You can see in the example that although the first `text` element has the `animatable` class, it doesn't move - that's because we're trying to animate the `text` element directly. The second one *does* move, because the `animatable` class is on a wrapping `g` element, so the animation get applied to that.

If you wrap your `text` elements in another tag as per the example, you should be able to animate them using the methods you're currently using.

Comment: this would be a great solution if it was only one map with one place that has to be animated. But this also has to work on maps with more than one place that has to animate.

Also I would like to avoid adding parent elements to all places in 20 maps manually.

Comment: Also I forgot to say that the elements will get different delays. So they don't have to move all at once but take turns.

Comment: I see your problem now (your question didn't mention that you'd have multiple elements inside the SVG). I've updated my answer above.

Comment: I've been bashing my head against this for an hour, my animations worked fine on Desktop / Android, but on my old iPhone, my `transform` animation refused to work and I couldn't figure out why, moved it from the `text` to the `g` and BAM off it went.